# How to make Prometheus alert description give both ratio and absolute numbers?

Tags: alert, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I currently have a Prometheus alert that fires when my success rate drops below 85%.

I would like to add the absolute numbers of the ratio to the alert description.  How do I do that?

My YAML currently looks like this (I cleaned up some extraneous details):

```
groups:
  - name: recording_rules
    rules:
    - record: number_of_successes_24h
      expr: avg(sum by(instance)(my_status{kubernetes_name="my-prom",timeRange="1d",status=~"success"}))
    - record: number_of_total_24h
      expr: avg(sum by(instance)(my_status{kubernetes_name="my-prom",timeRange="1d"}))
    - record: success_rate_24h
      expr: clamp_max(number_of_successes_24h / number_of_total_24h * 100, 100)

  - name: alerting_rules
    rules:
    - alert: LowSuccessRate24H
      expr: success_rate_24h < 85
      labels:
        severity: critical
      annotations:
        summary: "CRITICAL: Low success rate 24h"
        description: "Success rate in the last 24 hours went below 85% (value: {{ $value }}%)"
```

My question is, how do I add the `number_of_successes_24h` and `number_of_total_24h` into the description?
I read the official documentation at https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/alerting_rules/, but I got lost; I searched SO, but I didn't find anything relevant.

I read that there were extra details available in `$labels`, so I tried printing that as an example to see what was in it, but I got `map[__name__:success_rate_24h]`, and I couldn't figure out how to see inside that.

Partial answers and guides welcome.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simplified version of my `TasksMissing` alert, which outputs the number of tasks missing, the total number of tasks and the affected instances in the summary:

```
  - alert: TasksMissing
    expr: |
      job_env:up:ratio < .7
    for: 2m
    labels:
      severity: warning
    annotations:
      summary: Tasks missing for {{ $labels.job }} in {{ $labels.env }}
      description:
       '{{ with printf `job_env:up:count{job="%s",env="%s"} - job_env:up:sum{job="%s",env="%s"}` $labels.job $labels.env $labels.job $labels.env | query }}
          {{- . | first | value -}}
        {{ end }}
        of
        {{ with printf `job_env:up:count{job="%s",env="%s"}` $labels.job $labels.env | query }}
          {{- . | first | value -}}
        {{ end }}
        {{ $labels.job }} instances are missing in {{ $labels.env }}:
        {{ range printf `up{job="%s",env="%s"}==0` $labels.job $labels.env | query }}
          {{- .Labels.instance }}
        {{ end }}'
```

The resulting description is expected read something like "2 of 3 foo-service instances are missing in prod: foo01.prod.foo.org:8080 foo02.prod.foo.org:8080".

The idea is that you use Go templates to generate a query (by populating a template with values from `$labels` using `printf`) and then pipe that into the [Prometheus-defined `query` function](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/template_reference/#queries) and get back either one result (that you can handle using `with`) or multiple values (that you can iterate over using `range`). Then you can print either the timeseries value directly or some label (e.g. the instance name).

Comment: Thank you very much! I couldn't figure out what I was doing wrong. Your answer helped a lot!