# Prometheus: alert on drop in number of concurrent requests

Tags: prometheus

Given a Gauge metric `number_of_concurrent_requests` (an example), I need to send an alert when that value suddenly drops.

One way I thought about is comparing the current value to what it was 30 seconds ago, and if the difference is greater than 20% send an alert (of course 30 and 20 here are arbitrary).

The rule expression is something like:

```
(number_of_concurrent_requests - (number_of_concurrent_requests offset 30s)) / (number_of_concurrent_requests offset 30s) < -0.20
```

This, works, but:

1. Is this the best way to do it?
2. I want to show both the percentage and the current value in the alert, can I do it? In in the way the expression is shown above, `$value` contains the ratio (such as -0.34).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably average the number of requests over a longer period of time. E.g.:

```
number_of_concurrent_requests / avg_over_time(number_of_concurrent_requests[5m]) < .8
```

You can optionally add an offset to the denominator if you want to compare to an earlier period. And of course use whatever range you feel is most appropriate instead of `5m`.

Regarding your second question, in the template for your alert's description you can use the `printf` function to generate a PromQL query; pipe that into the [`query` function](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/template_reference/#functions); and output the first result. Something like this:

```
{{ with printf `number_of_concurrent_requests{job="%s",env="%s"}` $labels.job $labels.env | query }}
  {{- . | first | value -}}
{{ end }}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56662722/8657904) for more detail.